# How should tasks be named in the Kanban approach?

Tags: scrum, agile, kanban, user-stories, tasks

I'm currently working on an "End of Studies" project with a friend. We are making this inside an IT company. We chose Kanban because, for us, it would be a great moment to try something new since we've used Scrum before.

Before jumping into the work, let's say I have a user story like "Manage Clients." In Scrum, the tasks would be named Sprints. I read some documents about Kanban and I tried the following:

```
Release 1: Managing Clients.
------ Task 1: Add new client.
------ Task 2: Edit client info.
------ Task 3: Delete client.
```

What would be the name in Kanban of the tasks in Kanban for: `Add new client`, `Edit client info`, `Delete client`, and so on?

Comment: I'm struggling to understand what you want to get out of this question. Neither the Scrum framework nor the Kanban framework say anything about the naming convention for tasks or how they are broken down. That is totally up to the team. If possible, could you clarify your question?

Comment: I cleaned up the question a bit, but if the question is really about *what* to name tasks then it will likely need to be closed as an opinion poll. On the other hand, if it's a question about whether you *need* to name tasks, or how to break down tasks in a given framework, then it would be on-topic. If possible, please clarify the question further without invalidating existing answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly believe you're mixing up concepts, so I'll take some wild guesses here.

> In Scrum, the tasks would be named sprints.

You may mean

> In Scrum, the ***goals*** are ***defined*** per sprint.

Where the Sprint goal defines what is the ***value delivered*** within a given period of time. As Kanban doesn't have this period constraint, you'd like to know how to give visibility of this "intention of deliver value". In other words... your question may be

> In Kanban, how can I socialise what we're intended to do for the next "period of time" if I don't have a Sprint goal anymore, as I had in Scrum?

Simply put, you don't. Scrum has one constraint to ensure team is focused, which is the Sprint. Kanban uses *other types* of constraints ([WiP limit](https://www.atlassian.com/agile/kanban/wip-limits) is the most known) to achieve a similar result. Kanban moves away from the idea of a "single unit of value" delivered over a period of weeks (i.e. Sprint Goal) into a system where you deliver small parts of the same value in an incremental & continuous fashion.

So, back to your example

```
Release 1 : Managing Clients.
------ [Task 1] : Add new client.
------ [Task 2] : Edit client info.
------ [Task 3] : Delete client.
```

What you want is to give visibility of the incremental work towards the completion of the "Managing Clients" delivery. There's a few ways of giving this visibility and it'll depend on the tools you're using. You may use a [Swimlane](https://quire.io/blog/p/Kanban-board-swimlane.html) per deliverable. Beneath this swimlane, you have all the incremental parts of it. As the items in this swimlane are completed, anyone can observe the progress towards its completion.

Comment: Thank you. Very useful.

Answer (score 0):

In Scrum tasks are not to be confused with sprints. The sprint is a timebox, the tasks are just developer todo items.

In Kanban, tasks, if relevant at all, would be the names of the columns.

In this case I don't think you want to design a kanban system with columns you mentioned.

Is this supposed to be a kanban system to help you develop some client managing software? Or is the kanban system some actual business system that your software users use while managing clients?

Adding a new client, sounds like something the user of the software would do, rather than you as a developer of a software.

I don't know, this has nothing to do with Kanban but you might be confusing your user's tasks with the tasks you might have to do as a programmer.

Comment: I have to make a report that contains my workflow with Kanban(how I created the app) . So I set my chapter 1 : Managing clients. in this chapter and I named I- Task 1 : Add new client [ Explain how I did the task , diagrams , coding , design etc.. ] II- Task 2 : ..... I hope you did understand what I meant here.